# AnimatedContainer size does not animate if I don't give Height or Width

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

The `container` animates if I assign a `value` for `height` or `width`. But, I don't want to assign any `height` or  `width` to `container`.

Right now, the `container` size is automatically set when I assign a `child` to it. If the size of `child` changes, the `container` size is also changed.

My code looks like below

```
                      AnimatedContainer(
                        padding:
                            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          '$someText',
                          style: TextStyle(
                              color: Colors.amber,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              fontSize: 16),
                        ),
                      ),
```

If the value of `$someText` changes, the `container` width is also changed. But the `animation` does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of AnimatedContainer you should try AnimatedSize.

```
Container(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 5),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      color: Colors.white,
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
    ),
    child: AnimatedSize(
      vsync: this,
      duration: Duration(milliseconds: 200),
      child: Text(
        'Text',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.amber, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 16),
      ),
    ),
  ),
```

Also you have to add the TickerProviderStateMixin to your state for this.

Comment: If I have a lot of containers to animated, this will work? Will there be any performance issue if I put `TickerProviderStateMixin`?

Comment: Yes, this will work, but I don't have exact numbers on the performance .. I can only say that until now I never had any performance issues

Comment: When I use `AnimatedSize` it's animating all the properties of the container. I want only the `width` to animate. Is there any way to ignore animation for all other properties of `container`?

Comment: As you can see, I have `decoration` with `borderRadius` of 20. Now, it's animating `borderRadius` too. Border radius goes from 0 to 20 while animating and it looks ugly.

Comment: Then wrap AnimatedSize around the Text Widget and not the Container. Take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: Omg thank you so much! I could kiss you! :D